# Command in Vim to know where it's installed

Tags: windows, vim

I just wondering if is there a command in vim that shows you the folder where it's installed? I want something to useful for windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$VIMRUNTIME` points to a directory where most of the files needed by Vim are kept.
Try in vim `:echo $VIMRUNTIME`.

Thanks [@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) `$VIM` variable more to the point.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. It shows me `system32` path because it's using the command prompt program (`cmd.exe`).

Comment: Drop the `!`; this is a Vim-internal variable, no need to fork a shell.